# Flash AS3 erratic scrubber

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

**Introduction**

I made a video player that plays .mp4 files. It is based upon the FLVplaybackcomponent 2.5 in Flash Pro CS 5. It's basically a component with a movieclip interface (not a skin). the video plays fine, play/pause works and all that jazz.

**Problem**

The scrubber is erratic.

It seems to only be able to scrub in 10 second intervals and often behaves oddly (jumping to wrong locations).

All I seem to be doing is to take the total video time. Applying that time to a slider component so minimum is 0 and maximum is total video time. Then when the user changes the slider value it sets the playheadtime equal to the slider value.

If I trace out the values it seems fine, but the playheadtime is misbehaving.

If the slider displays 16 seconds and the playhead is made equal to 16 seconds it seems to snap at the closest **10 second interval**.

**Source**

Here is a test file showcasing the problem: 
http://rosefalk.dk/stuff/temp/stackoverflow/videoplayer_no_js.html

Here is the source with video and .fla: http://rosefalk.dk/stuff/temp/stackoverflow/stackoverflow-scrubberproblem.zip

**BONUS**

HTML players in some browsers seem to have no problem scrubbing the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video service used (DigiZuite) seems to re-encode the video with keyframes every 10 seconds. Re-encoding the video with keyframes every second fixed the problem (small video so it was VERY noticeable).